# JavaScript : Validation using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a requirement which should allow numericals, special characters, alphabets but not fullstop,comma,question mark, semicolon and exclamation marks and should contain atleast 6 characters.

Comment: Good. How is the search going? :)

Comment: You'll be more likely to get an answer if you show what you've already tried.

Answer (score 1):

String must be at least 6 characters and does not accept commas, periods, question marks, or exclamation marks.

```
/^[^.,?;!]{6,}$/
```